# Charting a subset of data in R

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and want to chart a subset of data of an excel file that I uploaded to R.

The file has 4 columns with a total of 690,000 rows/entries of mainly economic indicators
1. Country (Australia, UK, US, Singapore, India, China etc)
2. Indicator (GDP growth, inflation, bond yields, foreign direct investment etc)
3. Date (quarterly from beginning 1990 to end-2030)
4. Value

For example, I would like to plot a line chart in R, Australia's GDP growth from 2000 to 2018. Hence I would exclude entries of US, UK, inflation, dates that are after 2018. I understand this part for sure.

I figured I need to get a subset of the data first. But I can't get through this. What code do I use? Do I declare a variable first? I think I can plot it using one single command, but not sure how/where to start.

Images show the Australia GDP data and another one shows other rows (netherlands data)

[image]

[image]

Comment: In order to get the subset of the data you need, you can use the  `filter` function from the `tidyverse` package. For example, `filtered_dataset <- OE_All_Download_list %>% filter(Location=="Australia",Indicator=="GDP, real, annual growth")`. Then you can use `filtered_dataset` for your plot

Answer (score 0):

First you need the convenient libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# or library(tidyverse)
```

Then you can use what @fmarm already suggested in the comment and make a subset like this:

```
subset <- OE_All_Download_list %>% filter(Location=="Australia", Indicator == "GDP, real, annual growth")
```

and plot it with either base plots or ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data = subset, aes(x = Date, y = Value) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

For more help concerning plots, I can recommend to you the ["cookbook"](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/). For more questions about your task, try to search for questions about subsetting first. This may be flagged as a duplicate.